# Android application starts slowing down after some time

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am using graphview library to plot `50000` datapoint, it works when I plot random values without using array. But then I created a global string array to call it from another function. And when I run the program it crashes. I don't know why but when I debug the program and give sufficient time for each step the program works. I have also tested by debugging it and changing step at 0.1s or less the program bugs. I think the problem might be in calling 50000 array to get the value of a point.

```
        DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        if (time[i]!=null) {//Time 50000 datapoint, this is where the steps unable to get data if not sufficient time given.
            String strTime = "11/10/19-12:11:" + Integer.toString(i + 1) + ".23";
            Date d = null;
            try {
                d = sdf.parse(strTime);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DataPoint v = null;
            v = new DataPoint(d, 3);
            values[i] = v;
        }
```

Comment: is it crashing or what is happening?

Comment: Entire program crashes

Comment: Then post the crash log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetched the problem. I was taking the time array from async task. The time array was not loaded before it was called so the program was crashing. Thanks